# Redirection from MVC area redirects me to top level action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have following project structure. Where I have two Home and Account controller one inside Test Area and one at route level project. Now after login from area I want to redirect area's Home Index But it redirects me to route level Home Index.

[image]

Test Area Registration MapRoute

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Test_default",
                "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MVCAreaSample.Areas.Test.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

Base level maproute

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MVCAreaSample.Controllers" }
            );
```

Area Redirection action method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(TestModel test)
        {
            var candidateContext = "LoginContext";


            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, candidateContext, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), true, "Manjay");
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            //Check required for code contracts.
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginContext"] = candidateContext;
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I tried giving area name in route. It works in this case. But suppose I have proper authenication logic in both level than incase of

RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Test" });

It will give me login page of base level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to determine the existing area route and pass it across as a parameter in your redirect as follows:

```
var currentArea = RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = currentArea });
```

In order to go back up a level you simply specify a blank string for the area:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
```

Comment: I have updated my question. What if I have login module in both level. It will redirect me to the login page of above module.

Comment: It says An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.RouteData.get'

Comment: @TBAG Sorry I had missed out the `;` on the first line and it should just be `RoutData` please try again.

Comment: thats not the issue. Actually ViewContext  is not a static class. so we cannot acces RouteData

Comment: @TBAG Give me one min, will spin up an example.

Comment: Thanks hutchonoide. RouteData.DataTokens["area"]. This removes compilation error but I am being redirected to base level login page.

Comment: @TBAG You also need to make sure your `AreaName` is set to "Test" too but that code is not shown.

Comment: I double checked it. Area name is proper. But again I am being redirected to base level login page

Comment: I guess this is not problem with same name. This is some issue with form authentication token.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. It was some other issue in my code. I am able to redirect. I even dnt need to mention area name. But its good to know that I can pass area name in route value.

Comment: @TBAG Thanks, no problem